# apt-get; understanding where are package names referenced?

Tags: apt, package-management

I am trying to understand the `Unable to locate package` error.

In my case I am trying to [install zcash](https://github.com/zcash/zcash/wiki/Debian-binary-packages). After installing dependencies and following initial setup, I updated my sources.list file:

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.z.cash/ jessie main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/zcash.list
```

Then I ran `sudo apt-get update`

Looking at `/var/lib/apt/lists` I can see the installed packages (in this case from zcash):

```
/var/lib/apt/lists$ ls
apt.z.cash_dists_jessie_main_binary-amd64_Packages
apt.z.cash_dists_jessie_Release
apt.z.cash_dists_jessie_Release.gpg
```

However when I run `sudo apt-get install zcash` it seems to not recognise the name zcash:

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package zcash
```

I imagine there should be a name translation file (e.g. `zcash` to files referenced in `/var/lib/apt/lists`) - am I correct?

**In which file/directory should the name reference for an apt package be stored?** How would I check and debug this?

Comment: Search for package name in Synaptic. If synaptic can not find it, the package does not exist for the running debian instance. However, have you installed `apt-transport-https` and added the "Zcash master signing key" ? before `apt-get update`?

Comment: @Arrow thanks, yes I did the prior steps (and as far as I can tell it worked).

Comment: @Arrow thanks for the synaptic tip - zcash does not appear there

Comment: @Arrow it would appear that the `update` operation, whilst appearing to work, does not add zcash to the packages.

Comment: Then, the package is not installable, as synaptic use the same list of packages as apt-get, and, if a package does not appear in apt-get it is simply not-installable.

Comment: The stable version of debian is Stretch (not the now oldstable Jessie). Is that the version you are running? The repository you are adding is for Jessie (not Stretch). Maybe you have got a problem with that.

Comment: @Arrow  Running Debian 8 in virtualBox - perhaps that is also a factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just saw this and so I tested...

On a base install of Jessie in VirtualBox (amd64 netinstall, only "standard system utilities" and "ssh server") I had no problems getting `zcash` installed... However, my guess is that you didn't add the key to the repo...

Edited `/etc/apt/sources.list` and added the line

```
deb https://apt.z.cash/ jessie main
```

Add the `apt-transport-https`

```
apt-get install apt-transport-https
```

Do an `apt-get update`.  Argh... repo gpg key error.  Import/add the key for the repository -

```
wget -qO - https://apt.z.cash/zcash.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then did `apt-get update` and then `apt-get install zcash`

```
root@templatevm:~# apt-get install zcash
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libgomp1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgomp1 zcash
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 55 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,185 kB of archives.
After this operation, 12.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libgomp1 amd64 4.9.2-10 [37.8 kB]
Get:2 https://apt.z.cash/ jessie/main zcash amd64 1.0.10+1 [3,147 kB]
Fetched 3,185 kB in 8s (359 kB/s)                                                                                    
Selecting previously unselected package libgomp1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 29996 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgomp1_4.9.2-10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgomp1:amd64 (4.9.2-10) ...
Selecting previously unselected package zcash.
Preparing to unpack .../zcash_1.0.10+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking zcash (1.0.10+1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Setting up libgomp1:amd64 (4.9.2-10) ...
Setting up zcash (1.0.10+1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u7) ...
root@templatevm:~#
```

Comment: My error was in using an i386 image not amd64... thanks